# Add multiple users to a careers.stackoverflow.com employer account

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, jobs

I have a careers.stackoverflow.com employer account. I want my colleagues to also have access to the same account, but currently this does not seem to be possible.

One way I've found to hack this is to add one of my colleague's openid's to my account, which gives them access to stackoverflow as me. However, this gives them access to all of my stackoverflow activity, not just my employer page on careers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow has [discontinued](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415293) Stack Overflow Jobs and Developer Story on March 31, 2022.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have been talking about adding this and agree that it would be useful. That said, we haven't yet decided how we'll do this and at what time frame, so for now I'm marking this as status deferred. In the mean time, what you describe is the best way of doing this. In your case this is not ideal as you have your profile under the same account. I would recommend opening a new account for your employer activity, which you can then share, and keep your current account to yourself.